# Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "if" with knockout

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I am simply trying to create some checkboxes and inputs that get the data from database and saving it back to database after edit. But I am getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "if: function(){return $root.editAlarmValues }"
> Message: Unable to process binding "enable: function(){return $root.editAlarmValues().setAlarmValues() }"
> Message: $root.editAlarmValues(...).setAlarmValues is not a function

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I checked in the console and the values get mapped correctly to the array but they don't seem to bind to view. Any help will be highly appreciated!

Here is the code:

```
        <!--ko if: $root.editAlarmValues -->
       
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="iCheck: $root.editAlarmValues().setAlarmValues" class="large-check"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5 form-inline">
                    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="iCheck: $root.editAlarmValues().setOutputCurrentPPLowValue, enable: $root.editAlarmValues().setAlarmValues()" class="large-check"/>
                            <input type="text" id="OutputCurrentPPLowValue" data-bind="value: $root.editAlarmValues().outputCurrentPPLowValue, enable: $root.editAlarmValues().setOutputCurrentPPLowValue()" class="form-control" maxlength="30" />
                 </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="pull-right">

                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat" data-bind="event: {click: $root.editSave}">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- /ko -->
```

and script:

```
 var AlarmsViewModel = function (wellID) {

        function EditAlarms(setAlarmValues, setOutputCurrentPPLowValue, outputCurrentPPLowValue) {
            var self = this;
            self.setAlarmValues = ko.observable(setAlarmValues);
            self.setOutputCurrentPPLowValue = ko.observable(setOutputCurrentPPLowValue);
            self.outputCurrentPPLowValue = ko.observable(outputCurrentPPLowValue);
        }

        var self = this;
        self.wellID = ko.observable(wellID);
        self.editAlarmValues = ko.observableArray(); 
     
        self.init = function () {
            self.editAlarmInit();
        };

        self.editAlarmInit = function () {
            APIHelper.getData("/api/alarmapi/EditAlarms?wellID=" + self.wellID(), self.editAlarmsCallback, "");
        };

        self.editAlarmsCallback = function (data) {
            //Map results
            var temp = $.map(data.result, function (item) {
                return new EditAlarms(item.setAlarmValues, item.setOutputCurrentPPLowValue, item.outputCurrentPPLowValue);
            });
            self.editAlarmValues(temp);                
        };

        self.editSave = function () {
            var jsonData = ko.toJSON(self.editAlarmValues);        
            APIHelper.postData("/api/alarmapi/EditAlarmsPost", jsonData);
        };

        self.init();
    };

    var wellID = @ViewBag.WellID;
   
    ko.bindingHandlers.iCheck = {
        init: function (el, valueAccessor) {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            $(el).on("ifChanged", function () {
                observable(this.checked);
            });
        },

        update: function (el, valueAccessor) {
            var val = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            if (val) {
                $(el).iCheck('check');
            } else {
                $(el).iCheck('uncheck');
            }
        }
    };


    var vm = new AlarmsViewModel(wellID);
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want a `<!-- ko if: editAlarmValues -->`, you want a `<!-- ko foreach: editAlarmValues -->`. The `foreach` will not run when the target array is empty, so it fundamentally fulfills the same function.

Inside the `foreach`, the binding context is the `EditAlarms` object in question, so you should refer to its properties directly (`iCheck: setOutputCurrentPPLowValue` instead of `iCheck: $root.editAlarmValues().setOutputCurrentPPLowValue`).

Also think about your naming. `EditAlarms` is not a good name for a single object. The prefix `set...` should refer to a method that sets something. In this case it's just an observable property. `setAlarmValues` should be called `alarmValues`, and because it's not an array, it probably should actually be called `alarmValue`. And so on.

```html
<!-- ko foreach: editAlarmValues -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="iCheck: setAlarmValues" class="large-check">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5 form-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" class="large-check" data-bind="
            iCheck: setOutputCurrentPPLowValue,
            enable: setAlarmValues
        ">
        <input type="text" id="OutputCurrentPPLowValue" class="form-control" maxlength="30" data-bind="
            value: outputCurrentPPLowValue,
            enable: setOutputCurrentPPLowValue
        ">
     </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="pull-right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat" data-bind="click: $root.editSave">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Revised JS code (move the binding handler definitions to the top, don't nest viewmodels)

```
ko.bindingHandlers.iCheck = {
    init: function (el, valueAccessor) {
        var observable = valueAccessor();
        $(el).on("ifChanged", function () {
            observable(this.checked);
        });
    },
    update: function (el, valueAccessor) {
        var val = ko.unwap(valueAccessor());
        $(el).iCheck(val ? 'check' : 'uncheck');
    }
};

function EditAlarms(setAlarmValues, setOutputCurrentPPLowValue, outputCurrentPPLowValue) {
    this.setAlarmValues = ko.observable(setAlarmValues);
    this.setOutputCurrentPPLowValue = ko.observable(setOutputCurrentPPLowValue);
    this.outputCurrentPPLowValue = ko.observable(outputCurrentPPLowValue);
}

function AlarmsViewModel(wellID) {
    var self = this;

    self.wellID = ko.observable(wellID);
    self.editAlarmValues = ko.observableArray();

    self.editAlarmInit = function () {
        APIHelper.getData("/api/alarmapi/EditAlarms?wellID=" + self.wellID(), function (data) {
            var alarms = data.result.map(item => new EditAlarms(
                item.setAlarmValues,
                item.setOutputCurrentPPLowValue,
                item.outputCurrentPPLowValue
            ));
            self.editAlarmValues(alarms);
        });
    };
    self.editSave = function () {
        APIHelper.postData("/api/alarmapi/EditAlarmsPost", ko.toJSON(self.editAlarmValues));
    };

    self.editAlarmInit();
}

var vm = new AlarmsViewModel(@ViewBag.WellID);
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Comment: thank you! This helped with the error in question. I had to modify the binding handler to `update: function (el, valueAccessor) {
            var val = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            $(el).iCheck(val ? 'check' : 'uncheck');
        }` because I was getting error on unwrap and this cleared that error. Now the values are binding but they don't change the enabled as supposed to so when I check the `setAlarmValues` the following checkbox remains disabled.

Comment: @RalucaMicu Which version of knockout are you using? `ko.unwrap()` has been available *forever*.

Comment: I've changed iCheck with checked and now is working as expected. Thanks for the help!

Comment: knockout v3.4.2

Comment: @RalucaMicu Yeah, the *"How to create a knockout binding handler for xyz?"* really is a separate question. I've tried to figure out how iCheck works, but I've never worked with it before so it's hard for me to say what could be the issue after looking at it just for a couple of minutes.